# Repeated Measures ANOVA SPSS output

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, interpretation, spss

I had a question regarding the SPSS output of my RM Anova.
I am conducting a RM anova with two time points pre and post which are my within group. My data is distributed in three conditions which is my between group. And I have one covariate.

My output shows a within groups table and a between groups table.
I am not certain how to interpret each of the tables since the within groups has the interactions of the DV and the between groups variables, while the between groups has only the condition and the covariate as variables.

Comment: Could you add the output to your question?  Also, you can't have interactions of the DV and other variables. Interactions are among independent variables.